# Mnemonic Generation Using LSTM's | How do I make sure my Model Generates Meaningful Sentence Using a Loss Function?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, nlp, deep-learning

I'm working on project that generates mnemonics. I have a problem with my Model.

## My question is ,How do I make sure my Model Generates Meaningful Sentence Using a Loss Function?

## **Aim of the project**

To generate Mnemonics for a list of words. Given a list of words user wants to remember, the model will Output a meaningful, simple and easy to remember sentence which encapsulates the one-two first letters of the words that the user wants to remember in the words of Mnemonic to be generated. My model will receive only the first two letters of the words the user wants to remember as that is it carries all the information for the mnemonic to be generated.
[image]

## Dataset

I’m Using Kaggle’s 55000+ song lyrics data and the sentences in those lyrics contain 5 to 10 words and Mnemonic I want to generate also contain the same number of words.

## Input/Output Preprocessing.

I am iterating through all the sentences after removing punctuation and numbers and extracting first 2 letters from each word in a sentence and assigning a unique number to those pair of letters from a predefined dictionary which contains pairs of keys a key and a unique number as value. 
List of these unique number assigned while act as input and Glove vectors of those words will act as the output. At each time step LSTM model will take these unique numbers assigned to these words and will output the corresponding word’s GloVe vector.

[image]

## Model Architecture

I'm using LSTM's with 10 time steps.
At each time step the unique number associated with the pair of letters will be fed and the output will be the GloVe vector of the corresponding word.

[image]

```
optimizer=rmsprop(lr=0.0008)
model=Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=733,output_dim=40,input_length=12))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(250,return_sequences=True,activation='relu'),merge_mode='concat'))
Dropout(0.4)

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(350,return_sequences=True,activation='relu'),merge_mode='concat'))
Dropout(0.4)
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(332, activation='tanh')))
model.compile(loss='cosine_proximity',optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['acc'])
```

## Results:

My model is outputting Mnemonics which match the first two letters of each word in the input. But the mnemonic generated carries little to no meaning.
I have realized this problem is caused because of the way I’m training. The order of letter extracts from words is already ready for sentence formation. But this is not the same in case of while testing. The order with which I’m feeding the letter extracts of words may not have a high probability of sentence formation.
So I built a bigram for my data and feed that permutation that had the highest probability of sentence formation into my mnemonic generator model. Though there were some improvements, the sentence as a whole didn’t make any sense.
I’m stuck at this point.

#### Input

[image: Input]

#### Output

[image: Output]

## My question is,

## How do I make sure my Model Generates Meaningful Sentence? Using a Loss Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I have a couple of unrelated suggestions. I do not think you should output the GLoVe vector of each word. Why? Word2Vec approaches are meant to encapsulate word *meanings* and would probably not contain information about their spelling. However, the meaning is also helpful in order to produce a *meaningful* sentence. Thus, I would instead have the LSTM produce it's own hidden state after reading the first two letters of each word (just as you currently do). I would then have that sequence be unrolled (as you currently do) into sequences of *dimension one* (indexes into a index to word map). I would then take that output, process it through an embedding layer that maps the word indexes to their GLoVe embeddings, and I would run that through another output LSTM to produce more indexes. You can stack this as much as you want - but 2 or 3 levels will probably be good enough.

Even with these changes, it is unlikely you will see any success in generating easy-to-remember sentences. For that main issue, I think there are generally two ways you can go. The first is to augment your loss with some sense that the resulting sentence being a 'valid English sentence'. You can do this with some accuracy programtically by POS tagging the output sentence and adding loss relative to whether it follows a standard sentence structure (subject predicate adverbs direct-objects, etc). Though this result might be easier than the following alternative, It might not yield actually natural results.

I would recommend, in addition to training your model in it's current fashion, to use a GAN to judge if the output sentences are natural sentences. There are many resources of [Keras GANs](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN), so I do not think you need specific code in this answer. However, here is an outline of how your model should train logically:

1. Augment your current training with two additional phases.

   - first train the discriminator to judge whether or not the output sentence is natural. You can do this by having an LSTM model read sentences and giving a sigmoid output (0/1) to whether or not they are 'natural'. You can then train this model on some dataset of real sentences with 1 labels and your sentences with 0 labels at roughly a 50/50 split.
   - Then, in addition to the current loss function for actually generating the Mnemonics, add the loss that is the binary cross-entropy score for your generated sentences *with 1 (true)* labels. Be sure to obviously freeze the discriminator model while doing this.

Continue iterating over these two steps (training each for 1 epoch at a time) until you start to see more reasonable results. You may need to play with how much each loss term is weighted in the generator (your model) in order to get the correct trade-off between a correct mnemonic and an easy-to-remember sentence.

Comment: @VikasNS - I did answer your question but that does not necessarily make it right for stack overflow. I can not unilaterally re-open the question